# is the function ‎$‎\zeta‎(-r, ‎x+1) - ‎\zeta‎(-r) + ‎\frac{1}{2}x^r + ‎\frac{x^{r+1}}{r+1}‎$ ‎ convex?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, convex-analysis, special-functions

My problem : Let ‎‎$‎r<-1‎$ ‎be a‎ ‎fixed ‎real ‎number ‎and ‎define ‎the ‎function‎ $f:[1‎, +‎\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by ‎$‎f(x) = -x^r‎$‎. Hence,‎‎‎‎‎ $‎f‎$ ‎is ‎concave ‎and ‎increasing‎ ‎on ‎‎$‎[1, +\infty)‎$‎‎‎‎‎. ‎
‎My ‎q‎uestio‏n is:‎‎‎

‎‎‎‎‎‎Is the function  ‎‎‎‎$‎\zeta‎(-r, ‎x+1)-‎‎‎‎\zeta‎(-r) + ‎\frac{1}{2}x^r + ‎\frac{x^{r+1}}{r+1}‎$ ‎convex ‎on‎ $‎[1, +\infty)‎$?

Where ‎$‎‎‎‎\zeta‎(-r)‎$ ‎and ‎$‎\zeta‎(-r, ‎x+1)‎$ are ‎‎Riemann zeta function and
Hurwitz zeta function, respectivly.‎‎‎ ‎Can you help me?

I know that if ‎$‎f^{‎\prime‎‎\prime‎}(x)‎$ ‎exists ‎on ‎‎$‎(a, b)‎$‎, then ‎$‎f‎$ ‎is ‎convex ‎if ‎and ‎only ‎if ‎‎$‎‎f^{‎\prime‎‎\prime‎}(x)\geq 0‎$‎.

My attempt: Since $f$ is concave, so $‎\frac{1}{2}x^r + ‎\frac{x^{r+1}}{r+1}‎$ is ‎convex. On the other hand, the second derivative ‎$‎\zeta‎(-r, ‎x+1)‎$ is $r(r-1)\zeta(2-r, x+1)$, so $f^{\prime\prime}\geq 0$, and so ‎‎‎‎$‎\zeta‎(-r, ‎x+1)-‎‎‎‎\zeta‎(-r) + ‎\frac{1}{2}x^r + ‎\frac{x^{r+1}}{r+1}‎$ is ‎convex. is it right?

Comment: $\frac{x^{r+1}}{r+1}$ is concave: second derivative equal $r x^{r-1} < 0$, cause $r < -1$

Comment: Eugene Sirkiza. We can write $‎‎\frac{x^{r+1}}{r+1} =‎ ‎-(-‎\frac{x^{r+1}}{r+1}‎‎)‎$.

Comment: :) This means nothing. $\frac{x^{r+1}}{r+1}$ is concave for $r < -1$. $x^r$ and $\frac{x^{r+1}}{r+1}$ have different signs, so different convexity.

Comment: thanks. so the function is not convex.